# access each cell in row in a csv using key in python

Tags: python, csv

I maintain an excel sheet ( csv file) for doing configurations on a device
['**Product**', 'Direction', 'Speed', 'Port(int)', 'Port(hex)', 'Hex equal', 'Input Port', 'Output Port', '-description', '-enabled', '-ethernetType', '-inPort', '-ipProtocol', '-matchType', '-numberOfFlows', 'Ipv4 Src', 'ipv4 Dest', 'Ipv6 Src', 'Ipv6 Dest', 'TCP src Port', 'TCP dst Port']
['FC', '01', '00', '33', '21', 'FC010021', '4227924001', '4227989762', 'East-flow', 'yes', '0x800', '2', '6', 'Strict', '1', '1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.1', '2002::2', '2001::1', '80', '127']

1. Number of  rows are dynamic
2. I want to take few  cells in the row and pass to function
3. Configure ( direction,speed,port)
4. I want to traverse through the csv ( all rows) and call for all the rows
5. Ex: configure ( row[0].direction,row[0].speed,row[0].port)

I am not able to bring a loop and traverse the list and use each cell by its key  name.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried python's `csv` library?
It has all the required methods to read the csv file as a list of lists. Using this, you can solve your problem quite easily

1. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
2. https://pymotw.com/2/csv/
3. http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

You can use DictReader. You get the values in the CSV as a python dictionary.

```
import csv

file_handle = open("filename.csv", "r")
reader = csv.DictReader(file_handle)
for row in reader:
    configure(row['direction'], row['speed'], row['port'])
```

You can use CSV dialects for handling excel files (Reference: https://pymotw.com/2/csv/#dialects)

Based on the comment below, we can convert the dict reader to a list and access the list elements by index as follows:

```
import csv

file_handle = open("filename.csv", "r")
# convert the dictreader dictionary to a list of dictionaries
reader = list(csv.DictReader(file_handle)) 
configure(reader[0]['direction'], reader[0]['speed'], reader[0]['port'])
# ... and so on. (or you can use a loop here the way you want)
```

Comment: OP is using CSV files

Comment: Yes! I understand. The reference for excel files/dialects was to address this particular phrase: "I maintain a excel sheet".

Comment: okkhoy,, i see loop control still missing with your piece of code, i give print row['direction'] i see it prints all of them. no loop control variable. configure will be called three times ( number of row times, to be precise)

Comment: @MMR-bayarea-US  i am not sure i understand your question now, however, i have updated the answer to consider row indexed by row number. please check if that is what you need!